# R Plumber failing periodically when calling function from package

Tags: r, pm2, plumber

In our setup we have PM2 as a processmanagement system for R Plumbers on a windows server VM.

We are periodically experiencing a issue where the Plumber endpoint fails when calling a function from a package.
Plumber just returns a 500 without any message. When calling a function in the same Plumber file, which doesn't call a package function (base R) it's returning the correct respons. After a restart of the PM2 service and thereby the Plumber endpoint, everything is working as intended. Calling the same package from RGui works fine while the Plumber endpoint is in an errorstate.

This have happened to some Plumber endpoints but not to others and on different times. We have not yet been able to identify a pattern. Sometimes it will run for days without a hichup and others for a few hours. We have neither been able to force the issue.

There are absolutely no clues in either the eventviewer, log or surveillance.

Might there be any of you who perhaps have experienced a simular situation or perhaps might have an idea of where to look for a clue. :-)

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely somebody will know how to help based on no dependent packages and no code. All of my `plumber` troubleshooting experience (especially when I cannot reproduce it locally) is informed (if not resolved) by viewing logs on the plumber server; if not immediately obvious, add explicit logging to narrow down where in the code it is failing.

Comment: Regardless, please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.